# OpenPGP CFB mode for Tag18

Tags: c++, encryption, implementation, openpgp

The [bottom of page 50 in RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#page-50) describes how to encrypt plaintext data to store in the Symmetrically Encrypted Integrity Protected Data Packet (Tag 18). It says that the [CFB mode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-13.9) is used. I have written code for CFB so that it works as described in section 13.9 (for Symmetrically Encrypted Data Packets (Tag 9)). However, at page 50, it also says:

> Unlike the Symmetrically Encrypted Data Packet, no special CFB
> resynchronization is done after encrypting this prefix data.

So for Tag 18, the steps should look like:

> Step by step, here is the procedure:
>
> 1. The feedback register (FR) is set to the IV, which is all zeros.
> 2. FR is encrypted to produce FRE (FR Encrypted).  This is the
>    encryption of an all-zero value.
> 3. FRE is xored with the first BS octets of random data prefixed to
>    the plaintext to produce C[1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#page-50) through C[BS], the first BS octets
>    of ciphertext.
> 4. FR is loaded with C[[1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#page-50)] through C[BS].
> 5. FR is encrypted to produce FRE, the encryption of the first BS
>    octets of ciphertext.
> 6. The left two octets of FRE get xored with the next two octets of
>    data that were prefixed to the plaintext.  This produces C[BS+1]
>    and C[BS+2], the next two octets of ciphertext.
> 7. (̶T̶h̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶y̶n̶c̶h̶r̶o̶n̶i̶z̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶s̶t̶e̶p̶)̶ ̶F̶R̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶l̶o̶a̶d̶e̶d̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶C̶[̶3̶]̶ ̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶
>    C̶[̶B̶S̶+̶2̶]̶.̶
> 8. FR is encrypted to produce̶ FRE
> 9. FRE is xored with the first BS octets of the given plaintext, now
>    that we have finished encrypting the BS+2 octets of prefixed
>    data.  This produces C[BS+3] through C[BS+(BS+2)], the next BS
>    octets of ciphertext.
> 10. FR is loaded with C[BS+3] to C[BS + (BS+2)] (which is C11-C18 for
>     an 8-octet block).
>
>     11. FR is encrypted to produce FRE.
>     12. FRE is xored with the next BS octets of plaintext, to produce
>         the next BS octets of ciphertext.  These are loaded into FR, and
>         the process is repeated until the plaintext is used up.

Since the resynchronization step is not done, step 8 uses step 5's FRE, so it can be ignored right?

From the above steps, what did I misinterpret in the following code? I know that it works for Tag 9, with the resynchronisation step, but something is not adding up for Tag 18.

```
std::string CFB_encrypt(SymAlg * crypt, uint8_t packet, std::string data, std::string prefix){
    uint8_t BS = crypt -> blocksize() >> 3;
    // 1
    std::string IV(BS, 0);
    // 2
    std::string FR = IV;
    std::string FRE = crypt -> encrypt(FR);
    // 3
    FRE = xor_strings(FRE, prefix);
    std::string C = FRE;
    // 4
    FR = C;
    // 5
    FRE = crypt -> encrypt(FR);
    // 6
    C += xor_strings(FRE.substr(0, 2), prefix.substr(BS - 2, 2));
    // 7
    if (packet == 9){
        FR = C.substr(2, BS);
    }
    // 8
    FRE = crypt -> encrypt(FR);
    // 9
    C += xor_strings(FRE, data.substr(0, BS));
    unsigned int x = BS;
    while (x < data.size()){
        // 10
        FR = C.substr(x + 2, BS);
        // 11
        FRE = crypt -> encrypt(FR);
        // 12
        C += xor_strings(FRE, data.substr(x, BS));
        x += BS;
    }
    return C;
}
```

What did I miss?

Comment: By the way, it's a little weird that you're using `std::string` for binary data. It would confuse other programmers. I recommend using `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead. This interfaces with most crypto libraries better too, since they usually take `unsigned char*` rather than `char*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This chunk of code](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/blob/master/doc/openpgp.cfb.js.html) somehow works. I don't get it:

```
    else {
        plaintext = "  "+plaintext;
        // 9.  FRE is xored with the first 8 octets of the given plaintext, now
        //     that we have finished encrypting the 10 octets of prefixed data.
        //     This produces C11-C18, the next 8 octets of ciphertext.
        for (var i = 2; i &lt; block_size; i++) ciphertext += String.fromCharCode(FRE[i] ^ plaintext.charCodeAt(i));
        var tempCiphertext = ciphertext.substring(0,2*block_size).split('');
        var tempCiphertextString = ciphertext.substring(block_size);
        for(n=block_size; n&lt;plaintext.length; n+=block_size) {
            // 10. FR is loaded with C11-C18
            for (var i = 0; i &lt; block_size; i++) FR[i] = tempCiphertextString.charCodeAt(i);
            tempCiphertextString='';

            // 11. FR is encrypted to produce FRE.
            FRE = blockcipherencryptfn(FR, key);

            // 12. FRE is xored with the next 8 octets of plaintext, to produce the
            //     next 8 octets of ciphertext.  These are loaded into FR and the
            //     process is repeated until the plaintext is used up.
            for (var i = 0; i &lt; block_size; i++){ tempCiphertext.push(String.fromCharCode(FRE[i] ^ plaintext.charCodeAt(n+i)));
            tempCiphertextString += String.fromCharCode(FRE[i] ^ plaintext.charCodeAt(n+i));
            }
        }
        ciphertext = tempCiphertext.join('');

    }
    return ciphertext;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your step 3 here:

```
3. FRE is xored with the first BS octets of random data prefixed to the plaintext
```

doesn't match up with your code:

```
// 3
std::string C = FRE;
```

There is no xoring going on here. Try changing it to:

```
std::string C = xor_strings(FRE, prefix.substr(0,8));
```

Comment: thanks for noticing that, but this still doesnt answer how to encrypt properly for tag 18 packets